# MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem with plain style (no border)?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Is it doable to set **no border** to a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` ?

When I set `tracker.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;`, the button is well shown :

[image]

But when it is used, it's no more "Plain" :

[image]

Any thought to keep it with no border ?

**EDIT:** I also tried to set it as `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` every time the button is used, but it doesn't work :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    tracker.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
}
```

Thanks for help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the API allows that as of now, because the button needs a way to indicate that the button is currently active and therefore doesn't conform to the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41). Even though it could simply be done to changing the color of the compass to purple as in the Maps application. It also enforces the `Plain` style (no border) on the iPad currently, so they could theoretically make this an option in `iOS 7`.

Answer (score 0):

Want like this

[image]

Select bar button item and change style to plane.

[image]

Comment: Yes but no because you cannot add a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` button with the Interface Builder.

Comment: gimme the image.I don't know where to add it.

Comment: What image ? _Some added words to validate the comment_ :D